# VS 2005 line-spacing settings

Tags: visual-studio, settings

I can see how to change the fonts and colors in the IDE. Is there an option available to incrase line-spacing in the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. The line spacing is fixed - it's an IDE rather than a wordprocessor after all.